# Use case of Mmap directory factory with solr

Tags: solr, mmap, solrcloud

We are using solrcloud version 6.3 with java version 8 on 64 bit server. We have used MmapDirectoryFactory in our solrconfig. I am seeing lot of CPU, memory and load average spikes on different machines. We had raised the value of vm.max_map_count from 65530 to 262144. I want to understand if these issues can be related to this change.

Thanks.

Comment: how much RAM does you host have, and how much are you allocating to the solr jvm?

Comment: Each machine has 32 GB RAM and we have allocated 7Gb to solr JVM. We have index size of total 39 GB which is divided into 3 shards. Each shard is placed on a single machine and each shard has 13 GB index size.